# What's with Fractional Subtraction as an action on a number

Tags: arithmetic, fractions

This a simple (sort of stupid)  arithmetic based question that may require just the littlest bit of work.

Consider  $\cfrac {x}{a}$

I know that *division* is the number of times I'll have to remove a quantity $a$ from $x$ to end up with $0$ (the remainder). With $x, a \in  \mathbb Z$, **and $x > a$**, the first encounter may be that $x$ is completely divisible by $a$. 
  Say $\cfrac{4}{2}=2$. I've removed $2$ from $4$ *twice*. So there, my 
 ***action*** was removing $2$.
But look at $\cfrac{16}{100}$ or any representation of a decimal ($\in\mathbb R$). In $\cfrac{16}{100}$ I'm removing $100$ from $16$, only $0.16$ times. Now *that* as a real world ***action*** is quite an imaginary thing, no?Although I've *divided* $x$ by $a$, I've incompletely subtracted $a$ from $x$.

~(Please elaborate on improper fractions too, because I may not have the right basic idea about them)

To sum up my question here, I want to know how am I doing this  *subtraction* incompletely in these cases. How is this working in the real world like in computers and our minds? Do we  accept some kinds of operations to work like we accept something abnormal like the Twin slit experiment?

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  Did you mean $\frac 4 2 =2$?

Comment: You appear to be jumbling division and subtraction in some way, try being very clear about which operation you intend at which moment.

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry... I'll just edit that

Comment: And @lulu I meant division as repeated subtraction

Comment: But, as you remark, division isn't quite the same as repeated subtraction.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Yes. I don't think that operating with Natural and Real numbers in one expression is really useful as to understanding the working of multiplication and division.